# I have followed all the steps as required, however I am getting the error message

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, dns, resolution

```
flutterfire : The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I am seeing this error

```
At line:1 char:1
+ flutterfire configure
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutterfire:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: make sure to follow the cli setUp https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/